# How to unzip a file and extract when it gets notified by the Inotifier in Linux server

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Though I have installed inotify in Linux server its watcher function is working unless or until the **inotifywatch** is stopped it doesn't shows any result.

I have downloaded the inotify from **https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki**

**Ubuntu version 16.04.2 (GNU/Linux 4.13.0-32-generic x86_64)**

I wanted to know how can Inotify detect the file received via ftp connection and after detecting it have to unzip the file which consist of .csv file.

Without stopping the inotify watch function how can I track the file which are arrived via ftp. Which is stored in Linux system log file.

Comment: Please show your code.Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*